# Can only connect 2 clients to a TCP server?

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I'm building a server that listens on multiple ports for multiple clients to connect to. I'm using threads to handle each of these connections. However, when > 2 clients connect to a port the server doesn't handle the following connections. Not sure if it's a connection issue or a thread issue. New to both.

```
/** Thread started by the client that has connected
*
*
*
*/
void* client_listener(void* client){
    printf("Client for thread started\n");
    fflush(stdout);

   return NULL;
}




/** Listen for clients for this game
*
*
*
*/
void* listen_now(void* gameStruct){
    Game* thisGame = (Game*) gameStruct;

    listen(thisGame->sockfd, thisGame->totalPlayers);    
    int playerAdded = 0;  

    struct sockaddr_in cli_address;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_address); 

    //Keep accepting new connections 
    while((accept(thisGame->sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_address, &clilen) > 0)){    
        //Make the player in the game 
        printf("Total Players accepted is %d\n", playerAdded);
        fflush(stdout);
        //Make a client to store in the game struct
        Client* thisPlayer = make_client(thisGame, thisGame->clientSockfd[thisGame->gameId]); 

        thisPlayer->cli_address = cli_address;
        //Save values to this Client
        thisPlayer->id = playerAdded;
        pthread_t clientThread = thisPlayer->clientThread;
        //Create thread for this client
        pthread_create(&clientThread, NULL, client_listener, &thisPlayer);   
        playerAdded++;
     }
}

/** Get the socket for the port
* 
*
*/
int get_socket_for_port(Game* game, int port){
    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    game->server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    game->server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
    game->server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &game->server_address, sizeof(game->server_address))<0){
        printf("bind failed");

   }
   return sockfd;
}

/** Setup the game threads
*
*
*/
void setup_game(Server* server){
    pthread_t gameThreads[server->numberOfGames-1];
    Game* traversal = server->game;
    int gameId;
   //Loop through the games and setup their ports to listen on
    while(traversal!=NULL){
        traversal->clientSockfd = (int*) malloc(traversal->totalPlayers*sizeof(int));
        //Get the sockfd for the port
        int sockfd = get_socket_for_port(traversal, traversal->port);
        //Save the socketfd for this game to struct 
        traversal->gameId = gameId;
        traversal->sockfd = sockfd;

        //Create a gameThread    
        pthread_create(&gameThreads[gameId], NULL, *listen_now, traversal);    
        gameId++;
        traversal = traversal->nextGame;
    }
}
```

When I connect 4 times to ports the server is listening on. I get the following output. Not sure, and interested in learning what might be going on.

Output:
Total Players accepted is 0

Client thread started

Total Players accepted is 1

Client thread started

Total Players accepted is 2

Comment: Probably unrelated, but are you *sure* you want to pass `&thisPlayer` to the `client_listener` thread function? Why not plain `thisPlayer`?

Comment: Also note that when you pass `&clientThread` to the `pthread_create` function, it will *not* set `thisPlayer->clientThread`.

Comment: You don't save the socket returned by `accept()` for later use, so how do you expect to communicate with clients that connect to your server?

Comment: Oh and the second argument to the `listen` function is not the *total* number of connections allowed. It's simply the number of queued connections for `accept`, and should generally be kept quite small (`5` is a usual value).

Comment: Plus your `get_socket_for_port()` function doesn't return anything, so there's some undefined behavior when you assign a non-existent value to a variable where you call the function... Did your compiler not warn you about that? If using gcc or clang, always compile with at least `-Wall -Wextra` warning options, if not more. (Plus error handling if `bind()` fails needs to be more than just printing a message...)

Comment: [Beej's Guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/index.html) is a decent introduction to sockets and how to use them.